# netbeans 7.3.1 how do you go back to the last typed location?

Tags: netbeans

In netbans7.3.1 (windows 7),

Is there a way to go back to the last typed location?

This gets handy after performing a search within the same file, or after scrolling the current page up/down to look some things up.

To get back to where I was, I usually do a ctrl^Z and ctrl^Y back to back. I am curious to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Q, it takes you to last edit position